# ODBC connection through DSN

Tags: windows, odbc, tableau-api

> Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 127: The specified procedure could not be found. (XODBC64, C:\WINDOWS\System32\xodbc\xodbc64.dll).
>
> Unable to connect using the DSN named "XXXXXX". Check that the DSN exists and is a valid connection.

I am trying to connect to an ODBC through Tableau 9.2, does anyone know if this is possible or is this something I could solve?

I have tested the DSN and it works.

Comment: Try using the 32-bit version instead. Should be located somewhere like: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: hmm..Same error? Do you think Tableau is just not able to read of this type?

Comment: I'm not sure. You may just want to email their support team - they are usually pretty responsive.